# Simulating file upload via Postman with Vert.x backend

Tags: post, postman, vert.x

I'm working on backend in vert.x and try to simulate couple of things in Postman to make my life easier.

From following HTML form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fileSelect" type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm sending file uploads to vert.x. On server side, I'm performing following checks in Java code to ensure valid POST:

```
String contentType = req.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
boolean isMultipart = contentType != null && contentType.contains("multipart/form-data");
Set<FileUpload> uploads = context.fileUploads();
if (uploads.size() == 1 && (isMultipart)) {
// Do the processing    
}
```

If I execute this from browser, all works fine. If I'm trying to mock it via postman, `uploads.size` is always equal to 0

My current postman configuration for this specific request is:

- Header `Content-Type` set to `multipart/form-data`
- Body as `form-data`, with `key` set to `file`, `value` type set to `file` from drop down list and corresponding CSV file path selected.

Is the problem rooted in how vert.x is handling file uploads via `POST`, or Postman is unable to fully mimic browser behavior?

Thank you for help, as always!

Answer (score 1):

When you specify content type multipart then you should instruct vertx to process it properly by calling 'request.expectMultipart(true)' this way the multi part parser will parse the body. You can then set handlers for uploads and events related to the parsing of the body.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would ever fight with similar issue, somehow clearing all `headers` in postman makes it possible to work, i.e. I'm not setting `Content-type` anymore, which seems a bit strange...
Anyway, it works, I hope it will help someone someday.